# Animating a curve when drawn on canvas on click of a button

Tags: android, canvas

While drawing a curve using

```
 ArrayList<Integer> xP=new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayList<Integer> yP=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<maxX;i++)  {
        int y =some value;
        invalidate();

        xP.add(i);
        yP.add(y);

        canvas.drawPoint(xP.get(j), -yP.get(j), paint);

            }

}
```

i want curve to be drawn as point by point as if drawing with pen
,tried  using invalidate but its not working.Kindly guide where i am wrong.

Comment: read about `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnmator`

Comment: i have tried it but that is not working

Comment: **Edit:** Put the **PostInvalidate()** after the draw point, if you want it to draw slowly you are going to have to put a sleep after the PostInvalidate()

Comment: not animating still whole curve come as a whole

Comment: Property Animator Framework is designed for such animations, so it will work when used right, read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Comment: i have tried it ,but not animating as the way i want point by point as if drawing with a pen,it comes as a whole view alwaz

Comment: yes i know what you want, post your code then

Comment: this is my whole code of Ondraw,then just i am adding this view to my layout

Comment: and where is an Animator here?